# Someone passing ' only instigating remarks (not conflicting) to annoy you for the sake of starting an argument

Tags: single-word-requests

Let's consider it's my annoying younger brother that  I'm referring to.

This situation is complicated as I'm looking for a combination of Argumentative(minus the sense of disagreement)+ Annoying(plus the sense of wanting to argue).

This question might seem duplicate but the reasons why the following posts below don't satisfy my need is because

-[What is a word that could define someone who likes to cause conflict?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126385/what-is-a-word-that-could-define-someone-who-likes-to-cause-conflict)

He isn't 'sadist' or 'scheming to hurt'  but is just looking for an argument to irritate me.

-[Is there a word to describe someone who tends to disagree with others only to upset them?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79125/is-there-a-word-to-describe-someone-who-tends-to-disagree-with-others-only-to-up)

He doesn't 'disagree' with me as we're never in a discussion but give annoying answers(when asked something) with a sense of starting an argument.

**For Eg**:

**Me**(talking to myself): I need to eat something.
**My brother**: Eat yourself.

Even though he stated that he meant to say that I should help myself with the food but I know he was insinuating me to 'Eat Myself'.

**Me**(talking to myself after finishing one work): What should I do now?
**My brother**(in an undertone):Kill yourself.

That's irritating especially with a chuckle.

[If you've started to feel that this question is already stupid and irritating itself, then you must know how I feel considering I'm the target of the remarks and you could answer me, helping me to give a word for him.
Or if you're laughing at the absurdity of the situation, then you can just enjoy. Not to mention you'd be called a sadist.]

**Me** to **Him**: Can you bring Mom's  phone I have to refer something.
**He**: No. Don't take too many phones. There will be harmful radiations.

He wasn't concerned about the radiations but just being a 'Goldbrick' and HAD TO SAY SOMETHING!

**Me**: Where's my phone?
**He**(in a challenging tone): I hid it.

Even though I know he can't, he had to say that just to irritate me.
(Don't consider me to be a phone addict. These are some recent examples I can recall.)

I've referred to the previous posts and various dictionaries for the word but their definitions don't seem to fit my description. Please correct me if I'm wrong in perceiving their meanings.
Most of the words are based on the '***conflicting opinions***' or '***purposely disagreeing remarks***' that lead to annoyance and thus an argument.
While 'my brother' doesn't disagree at anything yet is successful in getting me annoyed.
You might say I'm over reacting and there's no need to be irritated or have a dispute but if that person is always hinting annoying remarks at you so as to start an argument, especially in a tone which is challenging for 'fighting words', it indeed is.
Honestly getting annoyed when in a discussion when someone disagrees with you is much better because at least you can put forth your opinion.
But in this case when the person is simply using one-liners to hint to vex you is frustrating.
I'm not asking how to deal with it. Just a word to describe him 'in a word' that I can use to inform others the way he messes with me.

I'm aware that 'annoying' and it's synonyms should be enough to use but I'm thinking of how to describe him to be 'looking-for-an-argument-kind also.'
I wonder if there could be an 'eponymous adjective' for my description.

These(my brother and if there are people like him) are the ones who have no better way to spend their time other than wanting to get into an argument. They are also extremely well when they actually get into one because they have the chutzpah to give the most stupid reasons and logic(just because they *have to say something* no matter how unnecessary it might be) until the other person(that's me) finally give up their logical senses and avert themselves.
It's one thing to annoy and just leave at that but basically he 's trying to be confrontational and contentious .

So I'm wondering if there is a real word not a hyphenated coinage for people like him. Or is he just a new species with a unique annoying talent, bestowed with giving annoying remarks/replies to start an argument even when not conflicting my ideas.

Kindly inform me if this somehow is a duplicate question or if there is no possible one word for fusing the two required qualities. I'll just delete it.

Comment: Your brother is [*goading*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/goad) ([*provoking*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/provoke)) you. Like most younger brothers, he appears to be something of a [*dipstick*](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=dipstick).

Comment: 'Goading' has a nice ring to it and 'dipstick' is usually my impulsive response. I think 'goading' can work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm British, so my little brother was a proper little *wind-up merchant* at times, too. A more formal word that describes our siblings would be a [teaser](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/teaser):

> 1. A person who causes repeated emotional pain, distress, or annoyance to another
> 2. One who is obnoxiously annoying

The link also contains plenty of synonyms that you could use.

I'd also suggest that you stop talking to yourself, as that will give him less opportunity to goad you :)

Comment: I agree 'teaser' could work. Thanks for the word. if I don't get any responses I'll accept this answer though I'm looking for a more specific term, if it exists.

Comment: Amen to your last suggestion!