# Someone whose sole aim is to make another person’s life difficult

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

What are some good words that have the meaning of doing something only to make another’s life difficult?

My ex is suing me for my car. He bought it for me and now wants it back.  I am in a different relationship happily married and he wants to hurt me any way he can. He’s a narcissistic jerk and we have court tomorrow for the car, so I’m looking for a word or word to describe the way he is being.

Comment: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/thesaurus-category/british/things-that-make-things-difficult

Comment: Your ex is being **vindictive**, or **petty** look for their synonyms if you want to expand your vocabulary. Zeeshan's link is not helpful, none of the words listed describes someone's personality

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/126427/44619

Comment: This question is **not** a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

You could describe the person as being *spiteful*

> adjective UK/ˈspaɪt.fəl/ disapproving ​ wanting to annoy, upset, or
>   hurt another person, especially in a small way, because you feel angry
>   towards them

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spiteful

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: It may help to at least show the definition from the source.  Providing just a link does not constitute an answer.

Answer (score -2):

"My ex is suing me for my car."
"doing something only to make another’s life difficult"

That makes it
[Vexatious litigation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vexatious_litigation) (WP)

> Vexatious litigation is legal action which is brought, regardless of its merits, solely to harass or subdue an adversary.

In general, they can be said to be a **vexatious personality**.

A **classic example** would be the anonymous down vote to this answer.