# What do you call someone who gives a deliberate unhelpful answer to a question?

Tags: single-word-requests

Person 1: "I need help with my Xbox console, it wont turn on! What should I do?"

Person 2: "Just buy a computer."

Comment: Also, there is no question there. It's a statement.

Comment: You are right, sorry guys. I have edited the example.

Comment: Seems like this is answered by [What is a word that could define someone who likes to cause conflict?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/126385/191178)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest **flippant**.

> Marked by disrespectful levity or casualness; pert:

*apologized for his flippant remark.*

[American Heritage Dictionary]

Comment: Hypernymic, probably overly.